# create combinations inside forloop php

Tags: php

I want to create a combination of words inside php for loop
here is my code

```
 $fromCity = 'LKO';
    $toCity   ='TRV';
    for($c=0;$c<count($data);$c++)
    {
       $viacities = $data[$c]['citycode']; // Here i will get single connecting city Eg.BOM DEL MAA COK BLR     

      /* out put i will get as BOM DEL BLR MAA COK 
       *  Now i want to create Route combinations as     
 -         LKODEL, LKOBOM , LKOBLR , LKOMAA , 
           LKOCOK , DELBOM , DELBLR , DELMAA,
           DELCOK , BOMBLR , BOMMAA , BOMMAA , 
           BLRMAA , BLRCOK , DELTRV , BOMTRV , 
           BLRTRV , MAATRV , COKTRV

       */
        $routCombinations = '**above combinations**'

     $fetchRoutes = fetchRoutes($routCombinations);

}
```

How to create such a combinations inside the loop

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php I don't know what the `Route combinations` are or what the `fetchRoutes` does..

Comment: @chris85 it is flight route combinations i will get city codes inside loop using that city code want to create combination

Comment: Posted answer for the question I think you are asking..

Comment: Questions or issues with either answer?

Answer (score 0):

You use concatenation to join strings/values. The [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in PHP is `.`. Here's how you'd use it in your code.

```
$fromCity = 'LKO';
$toCity   ='TRV';
$viacities = '';
for($c=0;$c<count($data);$c++) {
    $viacities .= ' ' . $data[$c]['citycode']; // Here i will get single connecting city Eg.BOM DEL MAA COK BLR     
    $routCombinations = '**above combinations**'
    $fetchRoutes = fetchRoutes($routCombinations);
}
```

Here's a longer write up from the manual on concatenation.

> There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. The second is the concatenating assignment operator ('.='), which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side. Please read Assignment Operators for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as :

> how to get all "A -> B" combinations, where A and B are cities in a flight route, and A is before B.

If so, you can do :

```
$fromCity = 'LKO';
$toCity   ='TRV';

$allCities = array($fromCity);
foreach ($data as $viacity) {
    $allCities[] = $viacity['citycode'];
}
$allCities[] = $toCity;

$routCombinations = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($allCities); $i++) {
    for ($j=i+1; $j<count($allCities); $j++) {
        $routCombinations[] = $allCities[$i].$allCities[$j];
    }
}

.... 
// If you need you can concatenate the array into a string : 
$routCombinationsString = implode(',',$routCombinations)
....
$fetchRoutes = fetchRoutes($routCombinations);
```